# OS-SIGNATURE_INVALID [22] failed in Tizen wearable sdk

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to run my sample app in Samsung galaxy gear s but I couldn't It's giving me error "`SIGNATURE_INVALID [22] failed`" in Tizen. I have followed all steps.

Comment: Which steps did you follow? Could you please add more details?

Comment: I have followed certification guide in  http://img-developer.samsung.com/gear/getting_started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually means the certificate that you created to start the process doesn't match the device profile that was downloaded. There are 3 parts to the Tizen Wearable signing process

1. Your certificate that you create using the Tizen IDE. This file is in ~/tizen-wearable-sdk-data/keystore/author.csr.
2. Your certificate that has been co-signed using the Samsung Developer account and returned to you in email in a file named author.crt
3. A device profile that is unique to the device you are debugging. This is created by the Samsung Developer site based on information you provide. The result is sent in an email as device_profile.xml. You sign this profile with your author certificate and install. If the signature used to sign this profile doesn't match the original author.csr, then it will fail.

The process isn't as simple as Android as you can self-sign Android APKs. Tizen/embedded Linux don't allow that.

I have some [slides from a talk I gave back in November](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyxy7jlz81bwxo9/8458_Cloninger.pdf?dl=0) at the Samsung Developer Conference. The main Samsung developer site had some inaccurate information at the time, so check out these as a reference.