# Gear S device is not displayed in Tizen IDE

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to run a simple hello world project on my Gear S.
I am following the tutorial provided by [tizen developer](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/first_app/first_app.htm) and [this website](http://denvycom.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-build-your-first-samsung-gear2-app-tizen/).

My problem is, it seems impossible to connect my device to the computer. I have connected the gear S to the computer, and I can actually browse its files in explorer. But when I hit `run` button in Tizen IDE, it gives me the following error:
"*There is no target to lunch*"

I would like to get things working, even with a simple hello world project. I would appreciate it if you could help me with this.

---

**>>> Solution <<<**
I followed the instructions in the answer below. Please see the comments to see how it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you go through the parts about creating a developer certificate and getting a device profile? This is the one thing that trips up developers because it's not immediately obvious from the tizen site. Turning on USB debugging, like you would do on Android, is not enough as the Tizen platform does not allow self-signed apps, even for testing.

You need to create a signing certificate, then create a device profile. Both of these steps require logging into the Samsung developer site. When you get the responses (via email), sign the profile with the certificate. After that is successful, you download the signed profile to the device using the Eclipse tools or a command line with sdb. Once all that is completed, you have a target to launch.

I have a similar answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862547/os-signature-invalid-22-failed-in-tizen-wearable-sdk/29899423#29899423). At that thread, I reference a [set of slides](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyxy7jlz81bwxo9/8458_Cloninger.pdf?dl=0) I presented at a developer conference in November that walks through this scenario.

Good luck

Comment: It's great that you have responded. In fact, I am following your instructions (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLQdDXSXLQk) line by line, but the problem is, I do not see the connected watch in the Conncetion Explorer to get the device ID. (I have enabled USB Debugging on the watch) Any suggestions?

Comment: Earlier you said you could use the File Explorer to see the file contents, so this suggests the USB driver is working. If USB Debugging is enabled, you should be able to use the 'sdb' command line tool to communicate with it. Try '~/tizen-wearable-sdk/tools/sdb devices'. If this doesn't work, then the Eclipse device connection window won't work either.

Comment: Yes, I can see it in Windows Explorer. I tried the command, and I got `List of devices attached` and nothing below it. Does that mean my watch is not working? How can I fix it?

Comment: Look in the device manager "My Computer>right click>manage". If USB debugging is enabled, you will see a device under USB Controllers named "Samsung SDB Interface". If you don't see this, the driver didn't load. On the machine I just tried this on, I have recently installed Windows 7 on and there's no development tools and it was able to load the driver from Windows update.  http://imgur.com/v1vmVdY

Comment: There is no sign of "Samsung SDB Interface" here.

Comment: That suggests to me that your watch isn't in USB Debugging mode. Settings>About Gear>USB Debugging. I haven't had to reset the watch ever to get this on, but you might need to. Do you have any devices that don't have drivers loaded?

Comment: USB Debugging mode is on. I checked it just now. Restarted it, restarted my computer, but still not there. Do you need me to take snapshots of current state of watch or computer?

Comment: What does your device manager on Windows show? Are there any uninstalled devices? Try a different USB cable. Make sure the watch is secure in it's cradle. Try a different USB port on the PC... I'm running out of ideas at that point. :-)

Comment: The problem was with the driver. I updated the driver and now I can see the device in Tizen IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this as an answer hoping anyone like me who used iMAC should get it without searching available forums. For MAC, If you are struggling with the same problem install Samsung smart switch from the below link.

http://www.samsung.com/in/support/smartswitch/

Comment: Does this work for transferring files from Gear S/S2 to a computer?

Comment: I didnt check transferring of files. But Gear S is not even recognized in Tizen IDE until I installed this smart switch.